# One line RegEx to match 6 alphanumeric with exactly 2 alphabetic

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out how to use positive lookahead to get this to work with no success.  I am playing with something similar to:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(\w{6})$
```

The only requirements are that
 1. the string is 6 characters
 2. has exactly 2 alphabetic and 4 digits.

So positive matches would be:

A0123A
AA0123
0123AA
A01A23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(\w6)$` matches a string that has at least 1 ASCII letter or digit (due to `(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])`) and only has 1 word character followed with a `6` symbol. So, it will match strings like `16` or `_6`, or `a6`. Thus, it will not work as you expect.

You may use

```
^(?=.{6}$)\d*(?:\p{L}\d*){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM1iU4/1)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{6}$)` - a check that makes sure there are 6 characters in the string
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `(?:\p{L}\d*){2}` - 2 sequences of a letter and 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string

If you need to limit the expression to matching ASCII letters and digits, replace `\p{L}` with `[a-zA-Z]` and `\d` with `[0-9]`.

Also, to make sure you match at the start and the very end of the string, use  `\z` anchor instead of `$`.